# How to find and plot eigenvalues of symbolic 6*6 matrix

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue

I have a symbolic 6x6 matrics that I must find eigenvalues and plot them.
I can't plot and I don't know what can I do.

```
    syms t H t1 t2 E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6 HH H1 v d H2 k a E;


t1=1;
t2=1.5*t1;
a=3;

H=[0 t2 0 0 0 t1  
    t2 0 t1 0 0 0
    0 t1 0 t2 0 0
    0 0 t2 0 t1 0
    0 0 0 t1 0 t2
    t1 0 0 0 t2 0];

H1=[0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0
    t1*exp(1i*k*a) 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0];

H2=[0 0 0 t1*exp(1i*k*a) 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0];

HH=H+H1+H2;

E=eig (HH)
```

I can't run the
     [v,D]=eig(HH)
and I don't kno how to plot 6 different E(K) function

sorry for poor english and ppor knowledge  of matlab and thanks for help!

Comment: So in short you're asking someone to code it for you?

Comment: Try to use the eigenvalue equation: det(HH - x.I) = 0, and solve *that*.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, and was able to do

```
[v,D]=eig(HH)
```

The diagonal values found in D will be your eigenvalues.  Since you don't specify exact values for k, the output is too long to post here, but here is an example using only first matrix H:

```
syms t H t1 t2 E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6 HH H1 v d H2 k a E;


t1=1;
t2=1.5*t1;
a=3;

H=[0 t2 0 0 0 t1  
   t2 0 t1 0 0 0
   0 t1 0 t2 0 0
   0 0 t2 0 t1 0
   0 0 0 t1 0 t2
   t1 0 0 0 t2 0];

HH=H+H+H;

[v,D]=eig(HH)
```

Output:

```
v =

-0.4082   -0.2485   -0.5211    0.1548   -0.5562    0.4082
 0.4082    0.5290    0.2312   -0.2471   -0.5218    0.4082
-0.4082   -0.3271    0.4758   -0.5591    0.1441    0.4082
 0.4082   -0.0642   -0.5738   -0.3283    0.4749    0.4082
-0.4082    0.5756    0.0453    0.4043    0.4121    0.4082
 0.4082   -0.4648    0.3425    0.5754    0.0469    0.4082

D =

-7.5000         0         0         0         0         0
      0   -3.9686         0         0         0         0
      0         0   -3.9686         0         0         0
      0         0         0    3.9686         0         0
      0         0         0         0    3.9686         0
      0         0         0         0         0    7.5000
```

If you are trying to plot eigenvalues for varying values of k, my suggestion is to make a loop:  Calculate the eigenvalues of HH for each value of k, and store these values into arrays.  From there the plot should be pretty straightforward.

[MATLAB documentation on plotting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html)